# how to link two jcomboboxes without repeat the values

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, combobox

i want to select an item from a comboBox which called names to display item in  comboBox asnaf .. i did it but the item appears twice and when i select another item from comboBox names the other items appends on the previous items as As it is shown in the image above .. and this is my code

```
 public void agent_comboBoxA() {
    try {

        String sql = "select * from `trading`";
        myStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String agent = rs.getString("agent_name");
            names.addItem(agent);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public void kind_comboBoxA()
{
    String sql = "select kind from trading where agent_name = ?";


    try {

        myStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        myStmt.setString(1,String.valueOf(names.getSelectedItem()));
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String kind = rs.getString("kind");
            asnaf.addItem(kind);
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public the defualt Constructor {

        agent_comboBoxA();

        names.addItemListener(e -> {
            kind_comboBoxA();
        });
    }
```

[this when repeat the same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dln9U.png)

[this when repeat the same value and the other value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfKYC.png)

Comment: I can see error here: `public the defualt Constructor`. Or just a demonstration?

Comment: yes just demonstration @YoungMillie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the other items appends on the previous items

Before you start appending new items you need to remove the old items.

See the `removeAllItems()` method from the `JComboBox` API.

Comment: put removeAllItems() in which location in the code ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanNashaat, did you read the first line of my answer?